# How to specify a callback to a method of an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, get

This is in a C# ASP.NET MVC 5 web application;  but that may not be important.  I am using jQuery version 1.10.2.

My question is about the jQuery `get` function and whether a method of an object, not merely an anonymous function, can be the `done` callback.

I have an instance of an object that is, for lack of a better term, a Manager;  it contains all the data I need and has methods on its prototype.  In one of those methods, I send an HttpGet request to the server, and wait for the `done` callback to be executed.   I would like the `done` callback to be another of the Manager's methods, such as in the following example.

```
function Manager( rootUrl )
{
  // (string): The root URL for the web app, including the trailing '/' separator.
  this.rootUrl = rootUrl;

  ...
}

Manager.prototype.editRecord = function ( recordId )
{
  // Send an HttpGet request, to get an HTML fragment for the view that edits the record.
  $.get( this.rootUrl + 'record/edit/' + recordId ).done( this.onRecordEditResponse );
}

Manager.prototype.onRecordEditResponse = function ( html )
{
  // Do something ...
}
```

When the server responds to the HttpGet request, the `onRecordEditResponse()` method is indeed called.   However, the value of `this` at that point is no longer that of the Manager instance;  it is probably the global `this`.   Thus, I have lost access to the Manager instance.

How can I specify the `done` callback so that it retains the Manager instance I require?

Comment: Somebody (maybe @Ouroborus ?) answered my question, but the answer went away before I could try it.   Where did the answer go?